# Providing IDs and resources in the URLs of PUT operation based on the resources in REST

Tags: web-services, http, rest, uri

Our System contains many documents, and each document can have 3 states say A , B and C.

**/doc/{docId}/A** - POST operation creates a doc with state A and also generates a new Id for state A.

Now this state A can be converted to state B or state C. Now to define this, URLs created are like
**/doc/{docId}/A/{aId}/B** - PUT operation will create new B from A.

**/doc/{docId}/A/{aId}/C** - PUT operation will create new C from A

Similary , State B can be converted to state C and vice versa.
To be complete Rest oriented we dont want to use RPC and so dont want to provide identification of state B or C in XML request.

So please let me know if there is a better way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are overloading the URI with state. If it's a single resource with three states, then it should have a single URI, and PUT should be used to change the state (using the PUT payload).